# can't get authentication with wireshark (http)

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to get authentication from an application that connects with tomcat apache by port 18080. 
I know user/pass, is only to check the application security to can use https instead http.
I sniff traffic with wireshark, I can see username but I can't see password in post. I use "label contains david". David is login username and I see...

```
POST /emThriftAPI/UserSession HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-thrift
Accept: application/x-thrift
User-Agent: C#/THttpClient
Host: win-56dqt3ueu2j:18080
Content-Length: 355
Connection: Keep-Alive


[1,"UserSession:IDL_Register",1,0,{"1":{"str":"emuser"},"2":{"str":"|GSR|WIN-56DQT3UEU2J|3152|1516698299|ChallengeSIDStr|2:237074EE80764FBDC5277571E95C35A9CD8C3AE7AB620707A701815F30A7E16F33BBA6E384317F5C360D12E9E6C24383A75C1B9F8EE28344F04B540F6ABCE3AD"},"3":{"str":"CLIENTE"},"4":{"str":"user"},"5":{"str":"GUI"},"6":{"str":"9.0.18.000"},"7":{"i64":600}}]HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-thrift
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 09:04:58 GMT
Connection: close

[1,"IDL_Register",2,0,{"0":{"rec":{"1":{"i32":1},"2":{"str":""},"3":{"str":"417EB1BE21513F85D2C1EA5D51BB5A22B96CD299D66393D0485F496E6D3FAF625DF2D10786CFBF94A8CB8AC216DB84C30CBE8D3DF8D6A89E5287ABBFD42D866D"},"4":{"str":"david"}}}}]
```

Please any help?

Comment: This isn't HTTP basic or digest authentication. It's happening in your application. So I don't think we can help you here, because we don't know how your application works. And if we did, it'd be a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Passwords are almost never transmitted in plain text. They are transmitted as a password hash

I am not familiar with your application but the third string looks like a hash.

It also looks like the server provided a challenge which may be used to calculate the hash.

The fact that you can see the username is bad news and the connection isn't encrypted.

Comment: Well I can see function in tomcat UserSession:IDL_Register. Is: Function: UserSession.IDL_Register

RegisterResponse IDL_Register(string userName,
                              string password,
                              string hostName,
                              string systemUser,
                              string clientType,
                              string clientVersion,
                              i64 timeout)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Almost all systems using passwords these day send the password to the server and the server verifies it against its database. In any sane implementation of this the value stored in the database will be a salted hash.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot that the server does the hashing rather than the client. This implementation may be a bit more clever and include a rotating challenge and have the client perform a hash using that before transmitting the credentials, though odd the developer thought of this and not encryption